# Do we need a "fur" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have a tag for [fur](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fur) (15 questions). Should any questions about fur be tagged [grooming](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grooming)?

Is there any benefit to having two separate tags?

Comment: I doubt anyone would ever search a 'fur' tag. 'Grooming' is good and the 'fur' tag could just be removed from questions not about grooming.

Comment: Few people woulg search or tag 'fur', even if it was the best tag, so it's really not a relevant tag. Also, between shedding and grooming, I think fur-related topics are covered. Is there no way to redirect tags when a user tries to use one?

Comment: I've made fur a synonym of grooming to ensure that it doesn't get used again.

Answer (score 3):

The [fur](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fur) tag seems unnecessary, I agree, but I don't think re-tagging for [grooming](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grooming) necessarily applies to all of the tagged questions in this case. I just see [fur](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fur) as being kind of redundant, or obvious, for the most part and unlikely to add much value as a filter.

Comment: Certainly [Is there any impact if I give freeze dry fish to my cat](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7195/is-there-any-impact-if-i-give-freeze-dry-fish-for-dogs-to-my-cat) doesn't need to be tagged 'grooming' or 'fur'. The 'fur' tag should just be removed.

Comment: @Zaralynda - I suspect they think it's good for the coat... I agree though.

Comment: John and @Zaralynda - the cat's fur has been falling out and OP thinks it's related to the change in food. That's the reason for the tag. (Not saying it necessarily should be there, just why OP included it.)

Comment: @starsplusplus - We get that, it's just a discussion as to whether it adds any value or not. I don't think that it does.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. It's a small sentence, easily missed, and your "I suspect they think it's good for the coat" made me think you had missed it.

Comment: @starsplusplus - No problem. My comment was with respect to feeding salmon in the first place.

Comment: That would be health

Comment: **[tag:fur] has been eliminated.**

Comment: Now, if only I could do that with the fur on my furniture... :D

Answer (score 0):

Two step process to fix [fur](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fur)

1. Evaluate existing questions and re-tag the [fur](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fur) questions away.
2. Synonym [fur](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fur) to [grooming](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grooming).
3. Profit.

Comment: I've been working on it! I just don't want to overwhelm the front page.

Comment: Don't sweat it, overwhelm is fine with me.

Comment: @Zaralynda - At this time, I've effectively reduced the number of questions tagged [tag:fur] down to 4.

Comment: **And at this time, there are no more questions tagged [tag:fur].**